# Deploying WordPress application on AWS ElasticBeanstalk - upload size

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have uploaded my WordPress application to amazons EB, a zip lets say `site.com.zip` (110MB).

Now from what I understand every time I want to do an update, I re-upload the application zip file.

This all works perfectly fine until the size of `site.com.zip` grows, apparently there is a limit of 500MB for a zip upload, however the WordPress installation also stores all of my upload images, this accounts for 100MB of my 110MB application zip file.

This `site.com\wp-content\uploads` directory is soon going to grow and go over the 500MB limit.

What is the best solution? I mean ideally I need to move the `uploads` into somewhere that is not the application zip.

Found a possible solution: https://wordpress.org/plugins/amazon-s3-and-cloudfront/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally the media files should be stored in a [S3 Bucket](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html). This will make your WordPress package smaller and also will allow easier scaling of your servers.

There are some plugins you will need to install to configure your WordPress communication with Amazon S3:

- [Amazon Web Services Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/amazon-web-services/)
- [WP Offload S3 Lite](https://wordpress.org/plugins/amazon-s3-and-cloudfront/)

Comment: So this confirms what I found, thanks. The only problem is the you have pay quite a lot for it to migrate your current media to S3.

Comment: Reviews also say to avoid it, not ideal.